# Send email using Script Task in SSIS with more than 8000 characters

Tags: html, email, ssis

I'm trying to send an email using Script Task in email but have a few issues. 
The body of the email is more than 8000 characters (HTML email) and it sends a blank email. I get the Body, EmailFrom, EmailTo and Subject from a function. (This is just one row. The body of the email gets generated using some views and some calculations) I have read that I need to use a foreach loop container and edit my script, but nothing is working atm for me.

My SSIS Control Flow looks like: 
1. Execute SQL Task: Select Body, From, To, Subject from dbo.Email_fn() 
Result Set : single row 
 and Result Set mapped to variables in the same order with name (0,1,2,3) 
2:Script Task: Read only variables: I have chosen all my variables from above.
My code looks like: (Please help me edit my code):
using System.Net.Mail;          // Added

namespace ST_df6618207373422d961b80ca8b6a56e2
{

```
{
    public void Main()
    {

        variables with hardcoded values.
        String SendMailFrom = Dts.Variables["SendMailFrom"].Value.ToString();
        String SendMailTo = Dts.Variables["SendMailTo"].Value.ToString();
        String SendMailSubject = Dts.Variables["SendMailSubject"].Value.ToString();
        String SendMailBody = Dts.Variables["SendMailBody"].Value.ToString();


         String SmtpServer = Dts.Variables["SmtpServer"].Value.ToString();
        String SmtpServer = Dts.Connections["My SMTP Connection Manager"].Properties["SmtpServer"].GetValue(Dts.Connections["My SMTP Connection Manager"]).ToString();


        MailMessage myHtmlFormattedMail = new MailMessage(SendMailFrom, SendMailTo, SendMailSubject, SendMailBody);
        myHtmlFormattedMail.IsBodyHtml = true;


        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpServer);
        mySmtpClient.Port = 2525; 
        mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlFormattedMail);


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

This sends a blank email because the body is more than 8000 characters and it gets truncated. How do I rectify this???? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try debug outputting in code to see that it was not lost before? this.FireInformation() etc